# writing reverse in the textbox

Tags: input

I want to input in a text box in reverse order Like a Urdu language.Is any input
property  to do it or any code?
direction:rtl; only start from end but the input text is at it is.It does'nt reverse
looking in the textbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use simple CSS

```
input[type=text] {
   text-align: right;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AJBmv/)

Updated:

```
input[type=text] {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

Comment: thanx for commenting But I don't want this..in this case if i am writing dheeraj it shows dheeraj. I want jareehd as i start typing from d.

Comment: ya so what you expect? jareehd?

Comment: @DheerajSharma If stubborn with the mirror letters than check this out http://jsfiddle.net/y7fVc/1/

Comment: Excellent use of CSS