# Right to left number input

Tags: html, css, text-align

I want to create an input where numbers are input from right to left but the text is aligned right.  I played with the [dir](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp) attribute and [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) but have had no luck so far.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0o0xq2s/1/).

```
<input type="number" dir="rtl">
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're after. Your question says "text is aligned right" but the text in your fiddle says "I'd like the numbers to be left aligned". If I type 1, 2, 3 what should happen?

Answer (score 4):

You need to handle this in css.

Your fiddle is updated here: https://jsfiddle.net/o0o0xq2s/4/, but the relevant code is:

HTML

```
<input class="right" type="number">
<br/>
I'd like the numbers to be left aligned so the digits grow to the  right as I type :(
```

CSS

```
.right {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

There is also an older stack overflow example here: [writing reverse in the textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554397/writing-reverse-in-the-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something that happens while entering values on a Calculator?
If yes, try the following :

`<tr>
    <td align="right">Present Value:</td>
    <td><input name="presentValue" type="text" size="20"     value='<fmt:formatNumber value="${tvm.presentValue}" minFractionDigits="2"     maxFractionDigits="2" />' >
    </td>
    </tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/pbgjtgm8/

Use both direction and text-align properties.

```
<input class="right" type="number">
    .right {
        direction: rtl;
        unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
        text-align: left;
    }
```