# How to position cursor in search field after placeholder

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am using Vue for a small app and I have an input type search. The problem is that the cursor is displayed in the beginning of the input, but I want it to be displayed after the placeholder text. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```css
.search {
  height: 36px;
  width: 256px;
  margin-right: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #76b1c5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 18px;
}
```

```html
<input
 type="search"
 name=""
 id=""
 class="search"
 placeholder="search" />
```

and my CSS:

```
.search {
  height: 36px;
  width: 256px;
  margin-right: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #76b1c5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Don’t see what the point of that would be - the placeholder is supposed to disappear as soon as the user types into the field. Are you sure you are not looking for a label instead?

Comment: You could just set the initial value to `search`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is **BAD UX** and not recommended at all. but if you insist, I'm not sure that you could create this with `placeholder`. probably you must give a default value to the input and remove that value when the user starts typing.

Comment: Maybe this can help :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15554426/11111723

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this given your current setup.

The reason being that the cursor appears at the same place that the placeholder text starts. So, no matter how you alter the placeholder text, or the cursor, they will always begin at the same place.

If you wish to disconnect the cursor from the placeholder text, then you will need to create separate elements in order to accomplish that. For example, using a label, or a div, or a span, or some combination of elements to have the text out of the flow of the document in order for it to be removable and separate from altering the layout. In addition, this would mean implementing the placeholder logic, or leaving the placeholder in place as a label.